# Psychopy builder expt. - how to add live updating text on screen

Tags: python, psychopy

I am creating an experiment using Psychopy builder.
The participant is presented with an image containing numbers, e.g. 10 and 20.
They enter what they think is the mean of the numbers, 15 in this case, and then press the spacebar to move on to the next image.

I am trying to have it so there is a display/box on screen that shows them their entry, as with larger numbers in the hundreds of thousands and millions I think they might lose track of what they have pressed. 
The ability to change their entry would be excellent also, but really I am most interested in them being able to see it on screen.

In builder I can't find a way to do this, and the ratings scale is not appropriate for huge numbers.

I found these solutions in code to do something that sounds like it:
http://www.psychopy.org/wiki/home.php/Snippets/LiveUpdatingText

However when I try to add them using the code insert function , or just adding them to the compiled script the screen locks up when I try to run the experiment. I am a novice at python, and am not sure where to start fixing this. Is what I'm trying to do possible?
I'm happy to provide some example code from the compiled builder experiment.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Those code snippets are designed for Coder, where you control everything that is happening and when. The same thing can be done in Builder, but you will have to amend the code to fit in with Builder's event loop cycle. i.e. Builder does certain things at the start of an experiment, on every trial, on every screen refresh and so on. So you can't just insert this sort of code without modification, because, for example, it attempts to wait indefinitely for a keypress. Builder meanwhile, is checking the keyboard every screen refresh (typically at 60 Hz), so if you try to wait indefinitely for a keypress in code, you'll be halting Builder from doing everything else it needs to do.

In essence, you just need to break up the code into snippets that go in the appropriate tab in a Builder Code Component (for code to be executed at experiment start, on each frame, and so on), and avoid indefinite functions like event.waitKeys() in favour of instantaneous checking via event.getKeys()

e.g. to adapt the second example from Jonas Lindeløv, in the "Begin Routine" tab, put:

```
chars = list('0123456789.') # the valid characters
meanText = '' # start with an empty answer on each trial
```

In the "Each Frame" tab, put something like:

```
response = event.getKeys() # get a list of keys pressed at this instant

if len(response) > 0: # if there was one,

    key = response[0] # just convenient shorthand 

    if key in chars:
        meanText = meanText + response[0]

    elif key == 'space':
        meanText = meanText + ' '

    elif key == 'backspace' and len(meanText) > 0:
        meanText = meanText[:-1]

    elif key == 'return':
        thisExp.addData('Answer', meanText) # save the response
        continueRoutine = False # finish this trial

# update the appropriate text stimulus with the current response value:
insertNameOfYourTextStimulusComponent.text = meanText
```